# while Inherit style in WPF it affect parent style

Tags: c#, xaml, styles, wpf-controls

In WPF i have a style for the control like below,

```
 <Style TargetType="local:CustomControl">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3,0,3,0" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
 </Style>
```

Now i need to override customcontrol border for some other place like below,

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomControl" BasedOn="{StaticResource  {x:Type local:CustomControl}}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
</Style>
```

My problem is when i am using above code it override the 1st written code. is my code is correct.

Note: the base style is only written with target type. i need to override that control border in some other place without affect base code.

is it possible ? please help me to resolve this problem.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare a `Style` **without** an `x:Key`, it will override the default style for that control.

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomControl">
```

So the code above will effect **all** `CustomControl` elements throughout the entire application (or within the scope).

If you **do not** want to override the base style, you can give your `Style` an `x:Key`, like so:

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomControl" x:Key="MyAwesomeStyle">
```

When you create your control, you will then have to reference the `Style`. Here's an example:

```
<local:CustomControl Style="{DynamicResource MyAwesomeStyle}" ... />
```

Comment: but i need   base style and also the derived style  both  for some places.

Comment: @gobi007 hope you will use the derived style at minimal places rather than base style. so add key to the derived style and use the key to the custom control which are all need the derived style. The compiler cannot just understand which customcontrol need base style and which customcontrol need derived style.

Comment: @Karuppasamy i need to apply base style for all the places. in some places i need to change some property of base style like border thickness. all other style properties must be applied all the places. the main purpose of my question is  is overrride a particular property(border thickness) value.

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally I saw some example which can be useful in solving the mentioned problem. In your example own custom control has been used, in my example - a button.

```
        <Grid>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource AddButtonStyle}" Tag="Add" Click="addClick" />
        </Grid>
```

Code for AddButtonStyle:

```
       <Style x:Key="AddButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">
          <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#x2705;"/>
       </Style>
```

AddButtonStyle based on AppBarButtonStyle. Below code for it.

```
        <Style x:Key="AppBarButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="40" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="88" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Symbol" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">. . .
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

On this example base, you must declare a Style with an x:Key, and should not set  any value to Content (in you example BorderThickness) property in the inherited style.